# Why dummy skyscrapers used to trap large monsters are being demolished one by one?

Tags: infrastructure, cities, creature-design, defense

Occasionally a large monster as tall as Empire State Building would emerge from the sea and goes into a rampage as it moves inland, we know this city lies in the middle of their migratory path and also they can proof extremely difficult to contain and put down.

As an international effort to collect a live specimen of the monster for study, one daring idea is to erect a series of tall heavy skyscrapers that are designed to collapse and fall onto the unsuspecting monsters thereby incapacitating them since they do not show positive responses to known drugs.

Before the next wave begin all dummy buildings had to be demolished as ordered by the international community, I'm wondering why is the plan abolished and is there better alternative to traping the flightless monster which will perspire thick corrosive effluvium capable of eating into metal and plastic when started?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here.  You've established a ridiculous, monster-movie premise, and then you're asking why, having built the trap, they're then demolishing it?

Comment: There's probably an infinite array of equally rediculous answers here... Godzilla gets classed as endangered species, gets given citizenship, its discovered they have flammable cladding and building codes still apply, people declare godzilla fake news, bank reposes them, USA detects oil underneath them and "brings them democracy", etc. etc.

Comment: VTC as this is story based. It's your story, you decide.

Comment: Because animal rights organizations came up :).

Comment: A city studded with skyscrapers designed to collapse when shaken.  We'll have to wait just a little while for some news stories to remind us why this is a bad thing ...

Comment: Mega-jenga, solitaire version.

Answer (score 4):

Someone figured out that [digging a huge hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapping_pit) (with optional spikes in the bottom), covered with tarpaulin and some earth is much cheaper, can be done rapidly (even just-in-time if a monster emerges), more ecology-friendly and to dispose of the monster, just bulldoze earth into the hole.

And the skyscrapers are blocking a rather valuable real estate area and create an aviation hazard.

Comment: like a quicksand trap.